# Visio Document Variable

Tags: c#, visio

I would like to store variable data inside of a Visio file similar to how you can in a Word file, but I am unable to find anything similar for Visio. A word example would be:

```
WordDocument.Variables("myVar").Value = "myVariable";
```

Alternatively, can you store a file (xml for instance) inside of a Visio file, then read and write to the file at run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option is already voiced by @Jon Fournier. DocumentSheet is a Visio way to store document-specific values. Check out also this article, which gives more details: http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2011/11/shapes-with-global-values.html

The second option could be Document.SolutionXmlElement, which allows you to store arbitrary XML fragment in Visio file for a document.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa218416.aspx

Third option could be (note that this is a bit archaic) to create a hidden master and store document data in there (in it's ShapeSheet).

Note that Visio does not support "CustomDocumentProperties" the way some other Office application do. See more information here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/85fbc601-1612-4e63-91f4-b900a59109bd/how-to-access-visio-document-properties-builtindocumentproperties-customdocumentproperties-from?forum=visiogeneral

Although there are also some "normal" office document properties which are exposed via API; likte "Title" and "Company" which can be accessed directly as document properties (i.e. "Document.Company"), user custom ole compound document properties not exposed directly and are not available with Visio API. If you are interested in that you might find out this topic useful: http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6535.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Document's DocumentSheet, which is a normal shapesheet object, so you can add User cells and store your data there.